# Using the Ivy plugin together with the Artifactory plugin in Jenkins/Hudson

Tags: hudson, ivy, jenkins, artifactory

I am trying to use the Ivy plugin (http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Ivy+Plugin) and the Artifactory plugin (http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin).

I am gettign the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ivy/core/IvyContext
at org.jfrog.build.extractor.listener.ArtifactoryBuildListener.buildStarted(ArtifactoryBuildListener.java:48)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.fireBuildStarted(Project.java:2077)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:746)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ivy.core.IvyContext
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
... 6 more
```

According to this bug report, https://issues.jfrog.org/jira/browse/HAP-65,

> The plugin intentionally relies on an external ivy configuration setup

But, nowhere can I find out how to do this external configuration. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by copying the ivy jar (ivy-2.2.0.jar) into the lib dir for the Artifactory plugin (.jenkins/plugins/artifactory/WEB-INF/lib). But I am sure there is a better way!